# How to test goodness of fit between two dataframes in R?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I know goodness-of-fit can be used to check the goodness between one dataset and a distribution type.  I wonder if it is possible to get the goodness for two dataframe in R?

```
e <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3)
f <- c(2,2,2,2,4,5)
g <- goodfit(e,f, method="MinChisq")
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a two column data frame to the function. In your example it will be

```
...
two_column_data <- cbind(e,f)
g <- goodfit(two_column_data, method = "MinChisq")
summary(g)

     Goodness-of-fit test for poisson distribution

         X^2 df  P(> X^2)
Pearson 3.772097  4 0.4377268
Warning message:
In summary.goodfit(g) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into R package **qualV** and function `generalME`. It provides various comparisons between observed and predicted values of the model. The package [is described](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v22/i08/) in Journal of Statistical Software.

The function `generalME` will work with two vectors, no need to combine them into one data.frame.